I unknowingly ate bovine collagen. What now?
I was at the gym and I got a protein shake and I didn’t know there was anything wrong with it but it turned out it had bovine collagen. What do I do, which god or goddess should I pray and repent to? Please give guidance.

You can pray to Lord Vishnu using this mantra -

ॐ अपवित्रः पवित्रो वा सर्वावस्थां गतोऽपि वा ।


यः स्मरेत्पुण्डरीकाक्षं स बाह्याभ्यन्तरः शुचिः ॥


Om Apavitrah Pavitro Vaa Sarva-Avasthaam Gato-[A]pi Vaa |


Yah Smaret-Punnddariikaakssam Sa Baahya-Abhyantarah Shucih ||


Meaning:
1: Om, if one is Apavitra (Impure) or Pavitra (Pure), or even in all other conditions, ...


2: ... He who remembers Pundarikaksha (Another name of Sri Vishnu, literally meaning with Lotus-like Eyes), He becomes Pure outwardly as well as inwardly.

